# Why am I having this error editing files with mkvpropedit?

Tags: windows, mkv

I use mkvpropedit to edit audio tracks in my movies and it works, MOSTLY. 
I found out today that for some of my movies (in .mkv of course) it give me this error:

```
Error: Updating the 'Tracks' element failed. Reason: The file could not be opened for writing.
Possible reasons are: the file is not a Matroska file; the file is write-protected; the file is locked by another process; you do not have permission to access the file.
```

These files are in the same folder of the others that actually works, and the permissions are all the same. 
I tried to remux one of this "corrupt movie" (the movies are perfectly fine to watch) and the edit works in that way. But since they're a lot, and also they're in the same folder with the "good ones", I'd rather to understand why it give me this error, instead of remux everything.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the file (s) have the "read only" attribute checked. If so, you can go to the **`containing folder -> properties -> uncheck "read-only"`** (this is to apply to all files and subfolders, if not, you can do it per file). Then try to run the command.

[image: Attributes: Read-only]